# linked server Local SQL account access remote server using windows authentication

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

I have two SQL servers. and both server accessed using windows authentication.
I setup Server 1 to connect server 2 using linked server.

Now I created Local SQL user (SQL Authentication) in server 1 and I need this user to access Server 2 through linked server.

[image]
I got this error

Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
Login failed for user 'Domain\user'.